# Garbage Collection taking place too soon

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'm digging into developing cross-platform code and after doing some research on handling exit codes in Windows and Linux I've pieced together the class below to handle keeping my console application alive. However, upon closure I receive the error:

> Process terminated. A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'Bot!Bot.Extensions.Environment.SignalHandler+SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler::Invoke'.

```cs
internal interface ISignalHandler
{
    void Set();
    void Wait();
    void Exit();
}

internal class SignalHandler : ISignalHandler
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private readonly SetConsoleCtrlHandler _setConsoleCtrlHandler;
    private bool _disposed;

    public SignalHandler()
    {
        if (!NativeLibrary.TryLoad("Kernel32", typeof(Library).Assembly, null, out var kernel)) return;
        if (NativeLibrary.TryGetExport(kernel, "SetConsoleCtrlHandler", out var handler))
            _setConsoleCtrlHandler =
                (SetConsoleCtrlHandler) Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(handler,
                    typeof(SetConsoleCtrlHandler));
    }

    public void Set()
    {
        if (_setConsoleCtrlHandler == null) Task.Factory.StartNew(UnixSignalHandler);
        else _setConsoleCtrlHandler(WindowsSignalHandler, true);
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        _resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        _resetEvent.Set();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void UnixSignalHandler()
    {
        UnixSignal[] signals =
        {
            new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGHUP),
            new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGINT),
            new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGQUIT),
            new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGABRT),
            new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGTERM)
        };

        UnixSignal.WaitAny(signals);
        Exit();
    }

    private bool WindowsSignalHandler(WindowsCtrlType signal)
    {
        switch (signal)
        {
            case WindowsCtrlType.CtrlCEvent:
            case WindowsCtrlType.CtrlBreakEvent:
            case WindowsCtrlType.CtrlCloseEvent:
            case WindowsCtrlType.CtrlLogoffEvent:
            case WindowsCtrlType.CtrlShutdownEvent:
                Exit();
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(signal), signal, null);
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;
        if (disposing) _resetEvent.Dispose();

        _disposed = true;
    }

    private delegate bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler handlerRoutine, bool add);

    private delegate bool SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler(WindowsCtrlType sig);

    private enum WindowsCtrlType
    {
        CtrlCEvent = 0,
        CtrlBreakEvent = 1,
        CtrlCloseEvent = 2,
        CtrlLogoffEvent = 5,
        CtrlShutdownEvent = 6
    }
}
```

From what I can find, _setConsoleCtrlHandler is being collected too soon, but I cannot determine how to prevent that from happening. Even calling GC.KeepAlive(_setConsoleCtrlHandler) shortly after assigning it, it still generates the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a class-scoped variable for your `WindowsSignalHandler`:

```
private readonly SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler
    _windowsSignalHandler = WindowsSignalHandler;
```

Then, pass that in to your method call:

```
_setConsoleCtrlHandler(_windowsSignalHandler, true);
```

That will ensure that your callback reference doesn't get collected because you are keeping a reference to it in your object.

Comment: Thank you. This is the gist of what I was reading in related posts as well--but it didn't even occur to me to set WindowsSignalHandler to a variable or it went over my head at the time.